# Free web mangement control panel

Tags: control-panel

Hey guys I need some help. I will also apologize for not being able to be more specific.

I'm looking for a specific web admin panel. that uses a login page via port 2222 or 4444. This is not vanilla forum or any forum.

So the only way I know how to make this a legit question is to ask what "free" control panels do you use to manage your web sites. This means files and domains.

Why do you use it? Where is it located?

Comment: I found the site I was thinking of and it is paid. http://www.directadmin.com/ Still looking for free solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ISPConfig](http://www.howtoforge.com/howtos/control-panels/ispconfig). It's free and there are loads of tutorials via the link above on how to install it.